# Div animating out but not in

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I have a Div that animates on leave, but not on enter. More specifically, the fade animation does work both ways, but the height animation only works on exit.

```
<transition v-on:enter="slideDown" v-on:leave="slideUp">
    <div v-show="!showForm" class="container-fluid">
```

And the jQuery:

```
slideDown(el, done) { $(el).slideDown().animate({ opacity: 1 },{ duration: 250 }); },
slideUp(el, done) { $(el).animate({ opacity: 0 }, { duration: 250 }).slideUp(); },
```

Comment: Most likely because when you `.slideDown` its opacity is 0, so it is sliding down, but you can't see it.  Why not put the calls in the same order:  `.animate.slideUp` so `.animate.slideDown`.  Or use fadeIn()

Comment: @freedomn-m `.slideDown` isn't being called at all. even if I change it to `$(el).slideDown();`, nothing happens. There's no transition.

Comment: Can you create a demo snippet / fiddle?

Comment: You're not calling `done`, which seems very strange.

Comment: @BillCriswell what's strange - the fact I don't call it or the fact it makes no difference?

Comment: I don't know if it's making no difference or not. I'm willing to bet it is, just not noticeable yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out I just needed the div to have display:none set before the animation begins:

```
    beforeEnter(el){
        $(el).css('display',"none");
        $(el).css('opacity', 0);
    },

<transition  v-on:before-enter="beforeEnter" v-on:enter="slideDown" v-on:leave="slideUp">
```